# Django Rest Framework, request POST, update if exists, create if not exists from mass data of POST request

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework, postman

I am building an API for users info data
I want to make that when the POST request, execute function "create", "update"

if from POST request user **exists**:

```
update (full_name, function, department, logon, system, lic_type )
```

if from POST request user **doesn't exist**:

```
create (user, full_name, function, department, logon, system, lic_type )
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Users(models.Model):

user = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
function = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True, null=True)
department = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True, null=True)
logon = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
system = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True, null=True)
lic_type = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True, null=True)
```

serizlizers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Users

class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    logon = serializers.DateTimeField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        # fields = '__all__'
        fields = ['user', 'full_name', 'function', 'department', 'logon', 'system', 'lic_type']
```

views.py

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework import status

from .models import Users
from .serializers import UsersSerializer
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication


@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@authentication_classes([BasicAuthentication])
def users_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = Users.objects.all()

        user = request.GET.get('user', None)
        if user is not None:
            users = users.filter(user__icontains=user)

        users_serializer = UsersSerializer(users, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(users_serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        users_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        users_serializer = UsersSerializer(data=users_data, many=True)
        if users_serializer.is_valid():
            users_serializer.save()
            return Response(users_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(users_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', views.users_list),
]
```

I could do like this, when POST request delete all from database and create data from POST request

```
elif request.method == 'POST':
    users = Users.objects.all()
    users.delete()
    users_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    users_serializer = UsersSerializer(data=users_data, many=True)
    if users_serializer.is_valid():
        users_serializer.save()
        return Response(users_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(users_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but instead I want to make update_or_create()
I tried like so, but this only creates empty row in database

```
    user_name = request.POST.get('user')
    user, created = Users.objects.update_or_create(user = user_name)
    user.full_name = request.POST.get('full_name')
    user.function = request.POST.get('function')
    user.department = request.POST.get('department')
    user.logon = request.POST.get('logon')
    user.system = request.POST.get('system')
    user.lic_type = request.POST.get('lic_type')
    user.save()
    return Response(user, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The best way is when a POST is there, you first retrieve the item from the database (using django's utility `get_object_or_404`) and have restframework update all fields you set as non-readonly in the serializer.

Example:

```
# on top import
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

....
elif request.method == 'POST':
    # add here the query you determine is user already exists, usually a unique ID or UUID
    user_object = get_object_or_404(Users, id=request.data.get('id'))

    users_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    users_serializer = UsersSerializer(user_object, data=users_data, many=True)
    if users_serializer.is_valid():
        users_serializer.save()
        return Response(users_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(users_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Something like this ought to work. You still need to tweak it a little the get object

Comment: hi @Boris,
thanks for your answer, but this does not work, and got error
`"detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Wel I wrote you need a little tweak, it seems that the json data you forward is not exactely correct. This has nothing to do with the question you wrote